# Has the Arquillian/Shrinkwrap community forum moved?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, maven-surefire-plugin, shrinkwrap

We've been successfully using Arquillian and Shrinkwrap for several months from within our environment, but we're bumping into an issue when running the tests inside our client's environment. The dependencies fail to resolve due to their proxy server.

Our Maven settings.xml file contains the needed proxy settings and the project builds fine. However, the Arquillian tests fail to find the needed dependencies.

We've tried many of the suggestions posted here (Thank you!) and elsewhere on the web without luck.

The main Arquillian site references their JBoss community forum (https://developer.jboss.org/en/arquillian?view=discussions) which was made read-only around the end of February.

Has this moved to another location?  Where's the appropriate place to get help with Arquillian?

Thank you!
- D

Comment: Hi. The official Arquillian forum has been living under http://discuss.arquillian.org/ for quite some time. Not sure about Shrinkwrap, but feel free to use that channel.

Obviously, StackOverflow is perfect for user questions both for Arquillian and Shrinkwrap - as you can see tags are watched :)

Comment: Please update your question with the test code - this way I will be able to help.